# Two successive calls to strcmp return different values given the same inputs

Tags: c, windows, gdb, mingw, mingw32

I'm using strcmp to compare several strings, usually on the order of hundreds or thousands of comparisons per program run.

I was noticing that, occasionally, strcmp would return non-zero when I knew that the strings were exactly the same. This would happen only once every few runs, and not predictably. Confused, I set a breakpoint when the return value of strcmp was non-zero using GDB so I could compare the strings manually immediately after the call to strcmp. Sure enough, it hit the breakpoint and I manually printed out both strings in GDB. They were exactly the same, including the null terminating character.

Even more confused, I modified the code to the following, to try to pinpoint problem by running strcmp twice on the exact same strings. In this case, I know that the `name` parameter should always match `R.ecos[0].name`:

```
Eco *get_eco(const char *name)
{
    int r1 = strcmp(R.ecos[0].name, name);
    int r2 = strcmp(R.ecos[0].name, name);
    if (r1) {
        //break here with GDB
    } else {
        return &R.ecos[0];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Again I run the program several times to try to produce the error. When the breakpoint hits, I print both r1 and r2 and see that r1 = 1 and r2 = 0.

My experience leads me to discount the possibility of a compiler bug or a bug within strcmp itself. This code is part of a game engine, so other threads are running for FMOD (audio) and GLFW3 (input), but none of these touch the memory here, so I have no reason to think there is something fishy going on with multithreading/race-conditions. What else could cause such a strange bug?

I'm using mingw32 on Windows, compiled with gcc, and I've tried two different versions of gcc and gdb, both producing the same results. This has NOT occurred on my Linux build, though due to the sporadic nature of the bug, I can't confirm with certainty that it isn't present on Linux, however I cannot reproduce it after dozens of runs on that OS.

Compiler flags:

```
-static -ggdb -g -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith \
                    -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes \
                    -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs \
                    -Winline -Wno-long-long -Wuninitialized \
                    -Wstrict-prototypes
```

EDIT: I've also run the program with ASAN on Linux and not encountered an errors

EDIT 2: After setting a hardware watchpoint on the address of both strings, e.g. `watch -l R.ecos[0].name[32]` I still hit the breakpoint in the code WITHOUT triggering the hardware watchpoints at all.

Comment: If you have multi threading, it may indeed have changed. Once you use a debugger, that alters the dynamics.

Comment: Have you tried a build with sanitizers enabled on Linux, or maybe with valgrind?

Comment: @ssbssa indeed I have built with ASAN on Linux and not encountered any errors

Comment: Does it only happen if you debug?

Comment: @ssbssa initially I thought so, but I was able to reproduce it during a non-gdb run as well, but it doesn't seem to occur as often

Comment: If you haven't already, I would try a memory debugger tool on windows.

Comment: Did you maybe compile with compiler optimizations active? If so, the line `int r2 = strcmp(R.ecos[0].name, name);` has possibly been optimized away, because that line does not change the observable behavior of the program. This could explain why `r2` does not have the expected value.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel good thought, but I am compiling with -O0 so I believe debugging shouldn't be affected in that case, unless I am mistasken

Comment: @EldenAbob: I believe you are correct, unless you are explicitly enabling some specific optimization with another command-line option (I guess you aren't).

Comment: I see that you discount the possibility, but my best guess would nevertheless be that you have a data race in your program (and likely many of them if you have the one).  We're unlikely to be able to diagnose it in detail without a [mre].

Comment: Added some compiler flags to the OP - no optimizations should occur with them. I am attempting to use gdb's watch command to look for memory changes, so far the bug is not triggering with the watchpoints set though - quite a Heisenbug

Comment: @AndreasWenzel even in such case GDB would complan with something like `(gdb) print r2` -> `<value optimized out>` - i.e. the compiler wouldn't emit debugging info for the optimized-out variable.

Comment: Even after setting a hardware watchpoint for the address pointed to by both strings, I still get the r1 == 1, r2 == 0 result WITHOUT either hardware watchpoint being triggered.

Comment: It may be worth running your program in [ThreadSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html), by compiling with `-fsanitize=thread`, to see whether it detects a race condition. This should also work on `gcc`. I doubt that this sanitizer exists on Windows `mingw32`, but you could test it on the Linux version of your program.

Comment: Elden Abob, I suspect a memory allocation mistake.  A [mcve] would be useful.

Comment: I ran it with -fsanitize=thread on my Linux build without any errors or issues. After trying to reproduce it on another Windows machine and failing to do so, I'm inclined to believe this issue is specific to my machine, which is troubling

Comment: It was corrupt Windows system files. A run of sfc /scannow detect 3 corrupt Windows .dll files. I have not reproduced the problem since the repair.

Answer (score 1):

> My experience leads me to discount the possibility of a compiler bug or a bug within strcmp itself.

There used to be a [bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12092) in GLIBC `strstr` long time ago, such bugs do sometimes exist. But you are correct in that this is very unlikely.

I would suggest making *local* copies of the strings before `strcmp`. That should provide a definitive answer as to whether you have a data race or a bug in `strcmp`.

It's fairly easy to do if there is a reasonable length limit:

```
Eco *get_eco(const char *name)
{
    char s1[MAXLEN], s2[MAXLEN];
    strcpy(s1, R.ecos[0].name);
    strcpy(s2, name);
    int r = strcmp(s1, s2);
    if (r) {
       // break here, examine s1, s2, name and R.ecos[0].name
    } else ...
```

Comment: After doing this, I hit the breakpoint and each string (s1, s2, name, and R.ecos[0].name) all contain the same string followed by a null terminator character.

Comment: @EldenAbob I _think_ that narrows it down to either a bug in `strcmp`, _or_ a faulty CPU. Have you been able to reproduce this on a different machine?

Comment: `char s1[MAXLEN]` is a problem if `MAXLEN` matches the _length_ or return value of `strlen(name)`.  `char s1[MAXLEN+1]` is better. A prior `assert(strlen(name) < MAXLEN && strlen(R.ecos[0].name) < MAXLEN)` is warranted.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the hardcoded size for each of these strings is 32, and the string in question "Evergreen Forest" (follow by null char) is well within that, but I take your point

Comment: @EmployedRussian I have not been able to reproduce this on another Windows machine or my Linux build.

Comment: @EldenAbob It's very difficult to have 2 separate Windows machines configured exactly the same, so this still leaves possible bad CPU or buggy `strcmp`. Are at least `mingw32` versions exactly the same, downloaded from the same place? Also, what is the reproduction rate? Does it change after you reboot? Does the faulty system pass `memtest86+` for 24h? These are the things I'd try if I were you.

Comment: @EmployedRussian they are exactly the same mingw32 installations, but one is on Windows 10, the other Windows 11. Memtest reports no errors. I'm at a loss and may have to convert the entire project over to Visual Studio just so I can debug it.

Comment: I believe it was corrupt Windows system files. A run of sfc /scannow detect 3 corrupt Windows .dll files. I have not reproduced the problem since the repair.